# react native style through parent

Tags: react-native, styles

style.js

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
    main: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: '#f0efce'
    },
    parent: {
        margin: 2,
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center"
    }
});
```

index.js

```
class index extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={style.main}>
                <View style={style.parent}>
                    <Text>... Sample1</Text>
                    <Text>... Sample2</Text>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}
```

My question is can i style `<Text>` from `<View style={style.parent}>`, what I want is to give `<Text>` a margin through `<View style={style.parent}>`. can somebody explain, I've only been learning react-native for a few days, ty..

Answer (score 0):

By applying parent style on view, each child of the parent style container would have contained the properties of style you applied like both `<Text>`

Answer (score 0):

You should give text styles like fontSize, fontFamily, color, etc to Text component and styles like margin, padding, backgroundColor to the View Component.

In the above case if you want text to have some space you should give margin to styles of Text Component like

```
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text style={{ margin: 2 }}>Sample 1</Text>
          <Text style={{ margin: 2 }}>Sample 2</Text>
        </View>
```